# How to append and remove html snippets on change of select list value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently attempting to use Jquery to append a list of audio tags html based on the value of a drop down list. The main problem is that when the select value changes the empty() and append() method are not injecting the html into the playlist div at all.

HTML initial state :

```
  <select name="querySong" id="currentPlaylist">

            <option value="playlist1">playlist 1</option>
            <option value="playlist2">playlist 2</option>
            <option value="playlist3">playlist 3</option>
  </select>
  <div class="playlist">

  </div>
```

HTML after changing select value (desired output) :

```
   <!-- playlist 1 selected in this case -->
  <select name="querySong" id="currentSong">
            <option value="playlist1">playlist 1</option>
            <option value="playlist2">playlist 2</option>
            <option value="playlist3">playlist 3</option>
  </select>
  <div class="playlist">
   <p> song 1
       <audio  controls>
       <source  src="music/song1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
   </p>     
    <p> song 2
       <audio  controls>
       <source  src="music/song2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
   </p>         
   </div>
```

Jquery currently being used :

```
$(document).on('change','#currentPlaylist',  function(e){
    // e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).find("option:selected").attr('value') == "song1") {

    // now load correct Playlist

    var playlist1 = [
           '<p> song 1',
           ' <audio  controls>',
           ' <source  src="music/song1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">',
            '</audio>',               
            '</p>',     
           '<p> song 2',
            '<audio  controls>',
            '<source  src="music/song2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">',
            '</audio>',
            '</p>',    
    ].join("\n");

    $(".playlist").empty().append(playlist1);
    }
    else if (
      ... continued logic for other select values

    });
```

Comment: Any error in console otherwise your code looks fine ?

Comment: no errors on the console at the moment, having no visual response either. The div remains empty after select changes

Comment: your select element with id `currentPlaylist` does not have `song1` value. And, btw, line `if($(this).find("option:selected").attr('value') == "song1") {` can be shortened to `if(this.value === "some-value") {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"song1" wans't an option's value of your `#currentPlaylist` select.

I changed that and it looks like your code is working just fine.

```js
$(document).on('change','#currentPlaylist',  function(e) {
    // e.preventDefault();

    if($(this).find("option:selected").attr('value') == "playlist2") {
    // now load correct Playlist

    var playlist1 = [
           '<p> song 2.1',
           ' <audio  controls>',
           ' <source  src="music/song1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">',
            '</audio>',               
            '</p>',     
           '<p> song 2.2',
            '<audio  controls>',
            '<source  src="music/song2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">',
            '</audio>',
            '</p>',    
    ].join("\n");

    $(".playlist").empty().append(playlist1);
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="querySong" id="currentPlaylist">

            <option value="playlist1">playlist 1</option>
            <option value="playlist2">playlist 2</option>
            <option value="playlist3">playlist 3</option>
  </select>

  <div class="playlist">
   <p> song 1
       <audio  controls>
       <source  src="music/song1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
   </p>     
    <p> song 2
       <audio  controls>
       <source  src="music/song2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
   </p>         
   </div>
```